# CoreStore refetch predicate NSFetchRequest issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest, corestore

if I got it clear I need to refetch monitor when I search something:

I have this function to refetch with provided string

```
func search(searchText: String) {
        self.monitor.refetch(.where(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", #keyPath(ListEntityType.name), searchText),
                             OrderBy<ListEntityType>(.ascending("name")))
    }
```

but this code is not compilable, only this below:

```
func search(searchText: String) {
        self.monitor.refetch(Where<ListEntityType>("name", isEqualTo: searchText),
                             OrderBy<ListEntityType>(.ascending("name")))
    }
```

But here is only equal operation, but I need to search not just entire word but as well substring with `format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@`

From CoreStore this is how function refetch looks like:

```
 public func refetch(_ fetchClauses: [FetchClause]) {

        self.refetch { (fetchRequest) in

            fetchClauses.forEach { $0.applyToFetchRequest(fetchRequest) }
        }
    }

public protocol FetchClause {

    func applyToFetchRequest<T>(_ fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<T>)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
.where(format: "%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", #keyPath(ListEntityType.name), searchText)
```

with

```
Where<ListEntityType>("%K CONTAINS[cd] %@", #keyPath(ListEntityType.name), searchText)
```

Another syntax sugar: You can get rid of the #keyPath references and use \ListEntityType.name instead

Comment: works great! thanks but \ListEntityType.name crashes with `Unrecognized selector -[_TtGCs24ReferenceWritableKeyPathC7Stacked14ExerciseEntityGSqSS__$ rangeOfString:]` if I use keyPath all works good.

Comment: you every time knows answer, I tried to google it, but have not succeeded, maybe I need to have more deep knowledges with CoreData, fetch requests and predicate. thanks so much for help!!!